# Work done by the gravitational Force and air resistance

Tags: energy, work

A 0.60 kg ball thrown vertically upward with an initial speed of 12 m/s rises to a height of 5.1 m. (A) What is the average force exerted by the air on the ball? (B) How high would the ball have gone if no air resistance acted on it?

work done by conservative force (gravity) + Work done by non conservative force = Change in total Mechanical energy

A) Let Fa be the force exerted by air
Let down be negative and up be positive

-mgh -Fa * h = (PE final + KE final) -(PE intitial + KE initial)

-mgh - Fa*h = mgh -1/2*mv^2

Fa*h = -2mgh +1/2mv^2

Fa = -3.29 N

This answer is however wrong, I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Correct answer given is 2.59 N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> work done by conservative force (gravity) + Work done by non conservative force = Change in total Mechanical energy

This is incorrect.  It should be either

> work done by conservative force (gravity) + Work done by non conservative force = Change in kinetic energy

or

> Work done by non conservative force = Change in total Mechanical energy

If you include the work done by gravity on the left-hand side and the change in potential gravitational energy on the right-hand side, you've double-counted the effect of gravity. This is because the work done by gravity over an object's motion is, by definition, the negative of the change in the gravitational potential energy.

Comment: thank you for your explaination